# SQL how to select user that is in all lines from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

if we have this database:

```
FORNECEDOR: (codFornecedor, nome)
ARTIGO: (codArtigo, nome, categoria)
CATALOGO: (nrEntrada, preço, nart, nfor)
   NOT NULL(nart)
   nart: FK ARTIGO (codArtigo)
   NOT NULL(nfor)
   nfor: FK FORNECEDOR(codFornecedor)
```

I want to get codFornecedor and nome from FORNECEDOR that is present in all lines of CATALOGO.

"Code and name of the suppliers that provide all the items available in the catalog"

How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Research "join" statements.
An inner join will only return the rows that have a match. Basic example:

```
SELECT codFornecedor, nome FROM FORNECEDOR 
JOIN CATALOGO on CATALOGO.nfor=FORNECEDOR.codFornecedor
```

The above list would give you duplicates if the fornecedor has more than one catalogo entry. to get rid of that you can use GROUP BY

Example...

```
SELECT codFornecedor, nome FROM FORNECEDOR 
JOIN CATALOGO on CATALOGO.nfor=FORNECEDOR.codFornecedor
GROUP BY codFornecedor
```